# Coffescript, Backbone - jQuery.ajax done callback function scope

Tags: jquery, ajax, backbone.js

I'm using AJAX to send a collection stringified to JSON. It gets decoded, validated and saved to session.

It works in Firefox - $_SESSION['key'] is available, it doesn't work in Chrome.

I think there is a problem with AJAX done firing too soon when I use *window.location.href = 'checkout'*. I wanted to fix it but I can't log from inside done callback or from ajaxdone method.

I don't understand why adding '=>' doesn't help. It caches the whole object to _this, doesn't it?

```
send: (data) ->
  console.log this
  jQuery
    .ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: 'checkout',
      data: {order: data},
      dataType: 'json',
      done: (data) => 
        this.ajaxdone()
    })
  this

ajaxdone: ->
  #window.location.href = 'checkout'
  console.log this
```

Comment: You need to "fatten" the other arrow: `send: (data) =>`

Comment: You should better use Backbone practices instead of rewriting your own ajax calls / callbacks [you can override sync method on purpose, for instance].

Comment: @moonwave99 I guess I should but the real question is: What do I do to successfully perform console.log from inside done callback? I thought I understand how JS works pretty well, seems i don't.

Comment: @Tallmaris but how does it change anything? it is still a method of an object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `done` option to [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). There is a `complete` option which is

> called when the request finishes (after success and error callbacks are executed).

so maybe you mean:

```
jQuery.ajax(
  #...
  complete: => @ajaxdone()
)
```

instead. There is a `done` method on [jqXHR](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR) so you could say:

```
jQuery.ajax(
  #...
).done => @ajaxdone()
```

but `done` is "An alternative construct to the `success` callback option" so it won't be called if there was an error. If you want `ajaxdone` to always get called then use `always` (which acts like the `complete` option):

```
jQuery.ajax(
  #...
).always => @ajaxdone()
```